# jquery list item class toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple function to toggle list item class from "active" to "inactive". What is the most efficient way (i.e., using the least amount of code) to set all other list items to "inactive" so that there can only be one "active" list item? Please see below for an example. Thank you

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li id="one" class="active">One</li>
    <li id="two" class="inactive">Two</li>
    <li id="three" class="inactive">Three</li>
    <li id="four" class="inactive">Four</li>
    <li id="five" class="inactive">Five</li>
</ul>

<script>
    $('#one').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("inactive")) {
            $(this).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can work:

```
$('.menu li').click(function () {
    $('.menu li').not(this).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
    $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
});
```

or

```
$('.menu li').click(function () {
    $('.menu li').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
    $(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
});
```

The second method is shorter, but slower.

http://jsperf.com/toggle-vs-add-remove

**Edit:** This one is shorter and faster:

```
$('.menu li').click(function () {
    $('.menu li').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

If performance is really a problem you can store your menu in a variable and perform operations on this variable, like:

```
var $menu = $('.menu li');
$menu.click(function () {
        $menu.not(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: You should use the toggleClass() function instead of addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');

Comment: @glautrou True, but it is slower. Added it to my answer anyway.

Comment: I edited your answer, if perforance is a problem (I don't think so) that could be improved and we don't need to keep the "inactive" class (by default it is inactive)

Answer (score 1):

For brevity:

```
$('ul.menu li').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().attr('class', 'inactive').end().toggleClass('inactive active');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qu4Nv/) (127 characters, whitespace-removed character-count: 115).

[Character-counts at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PKgHp/3/), since brevity was the intent, it seems.

Unfortunately, given the problem identified in the comments, below, a corrected implementation is somewhat more verbose than the (currently-accepted answer), alternatives being:

```
$('ul.menu li').click(function () {
    var t = this;
    $(this).siblings().add(t).attr('class', function (){
        return t === this ? 'active' : 'inactive';
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qu4Nv/2/) (174 characters, whitespace-removed character-count: 133).

Or:

```
$('ul.menu li').click(function () {
    var t = this;
    $(this).parent().children().attr('class', function (){
        return t === this ? 'active' : 'inactive';
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qu4Nv/1/) (176 characters, whitespace-removed character-count: 135).

Of course, white space-removed jQuery does become somewhat *unreadable*, but still: I claim the, uh, *moral* victory...

References:

- [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/).
- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
- [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: @Karl: thanks! I hadn't spotted that and, unfortunately, was unable to correct that while *also* maintaining the brevity. Though that's more due to (necessary) caching of the variable, as well as the indentation and new-lines than actual visible-characters on screen. So, while I maintain my so-called 'moral-victory,' I sort of have to concede defeat. Sadly... =)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
    $('ul li').each(function() {
       $(this).removeClass('active'); 
    });
    $(this).addClass('active');  
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KxGzh/)

Answer (score 0):

If SEO is not important and to use the less amount of code I would say use a radio-button list.
Then you can style and interact in JavaScript by using the ":checked" selector.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using jQuery UI, you can take advantage of the selectable function. That would get you what you want with the least amount of code.
http://jqueryui.com/selectable/