# (De-)activating navbar items in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to change the background colour of a navbar item  upon click by setting it active. The menu item corresponding to the left page should be deactivated, i.e. its background colour should be set back to normal.

There are two problems:

1. When using `data-toggle="pill"`, the `href` does not work anymore (therefore I left it out)
2. Remembering the previous page is not working because the global variable `previousID` is not overwritten. As a consequence, the previously selected menu item is not deactivated.

Here's the code:

```js
 var previousID = "navbar-index";
 $("li").click(function() {
   var currentID = $(this).attr("id");
   alert("current ID: " + currentID);
   document.getElementById(currentID).setAttribute('class', 'active');
   alert("previous ID: " + previousID);
   document.getElementById(previousID).removeAttribute('class', 'active');
   previousID = currentID;
 });
```

```css
/*.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
}*/

h4,
h5,
h6,
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
ul,
ol {
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #777;
}
body a {
  transition: 0.5s all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s all;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s all;
  -o-transition: 0.5s all;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s all;
}
.header {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2em 0;
  border-top: 3px solid #2ABB9B;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #2ABB9B;
}
.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #444;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #3e897a;
}
.navbar-brand .fa {
  color: #2abb9b;
}
.menu {
  float: right;
}
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.menu li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #777;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#nav .current a {
  color: #2ABB9B;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  /*color: #94ddcd;*/
  color: #104a3e;
  /*background: #fff !important;*/
  background: #a9e3d7 !important;
}
.menu li.active a {
  color: #000000;
  /*background: #fff !important;*/
  background: #ff0000 !important;
}
.toggleMenu {
  display: none;
  padding: 4px 5px 0px 5px;
  border-radius: 2em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
  -moz-border-radius: 2em;
  -o-border-radius: 2em;
}
.nav:before,
.nav:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.nav:after {
  clear: both;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .menu {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .active {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu li a {
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0;
  }
  .nav {
    list-style: none;
    *zoom: 1;
    width: 95%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    background: #051619;
    top: 86px;
    z-index: 9999;
    border: 1px solid #B11D1D;
  }
  .menu li a span {
    text-align: center;
    top: 15px;
  }
  .nav li ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu ul {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .nav > li.hover > ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .nav ul {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav > li.hover > ul,
  .nav li li.hover ul {
    position: static;
  }
  .nav li a {
    border-top: 1px solid #B11D1D;
    background: #fff;
  }
  .nav li:first-child a {
    border-top: none;
  }
}
.banner {
  background: url(../images/banner.jpg) no-repeat center;
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.banner-info {
  margin-top: 8em;
}
.banner-info h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #eee;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  margin: 0em;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.banner-info p {
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.content_white {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3em 0;
}
.content_white h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.content_white p {
  color: #777;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 0.6em;
}
.featured_content {
  background: #2ABB9B;
}
.feature_grid1 {
  width: 23.5%;
  margin-right: 2em;
  border-right: 1px solid #5fccb4;
  padding: 4em 2em 4em 0;
}
.feature_grid2 {
  width: 21%;
  padding: 4em 0;
}
.feature_grid1 .fa,
.feature_grid2 .fa {
  color: #e5e52d;
}
h3.m_1 {
  padding: 0.8em 0;
  margin: 0;
}
h3.m_1 a {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #4ca390;
}
h3.m_1 a:hover {
  color: #e5e52d;
}
p.m_2 {
  color: #e9f8f5;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.banner_btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #2ABB9B;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.banner_btn:hover {
  background: #22967c;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.feature_btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #5fccb4;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.feature_btn:hover {
  background: #e5e52d;
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nbs-flexisel-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.nbs-flexisel-ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 9999px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.nbs-flexisel-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 3em 0;
}
.nbs-flexisel-item {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.nbs-flexisel-item > img {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.nbs-flexisel-nav-left,
.nbs-flexisel-nav-right {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-top: -8.6em;
}
.nbs-flexisel-nav-left {
  left: 32.5em;
  background: url(../images/img-sprite.png) no-repeat -99px -101px;
}
.nbs-flexisel-nav-right {
  right: 35em;
  background: url(../images/img-sprite.png) no-repeat -133px -102px;
}
a:focus {
  outline: 0px;
}
.fa {
  color: #2ABB9B;
}
.footer_bottom {
  padding: 2em 0;
  background: #2ABB9B;
}
.copy {
  text-align: center;
}
.copy p {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fff;
}
.copy p a {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
.copy p a:hover {
  color: #e5e52d;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.about {
  background: #555;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
  background: url(../images/title-bg.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 180px;
}
.title-section {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.title-section h1 {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  line-height: 58px;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #555;
}
.title-section ul {
  background: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 9px 0 10px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #597275;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.title-section ul li {
  line-height: 18px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #5f6775;
}
.title-section ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}
h3.m_2 {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.service_box {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.service_box .fa {
  color: #2ABB9B;
}
.service_box h2 {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #5d5f60;
  padding-top: 0.3em;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.service_box h5 a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #555;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.service_box h5 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e4551d;
}
.service_box p {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #777;
  margin-bottom: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  text-align: left;
}
.about-info {
  padding: 4em 0;
}
.about-info h2 {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.about-info h3,
.about_content h3 {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.about_content {
  padding: 1em 0 4em 0;
}
.about_content img {
  padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
  float: left;
}
.highlight-info {
  background: url(../images/lab.jpg) center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6em 0;
}
.highlight-info h4 {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
}
.testimonial-solid {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.carousel-indicators {
  bottom: -40px;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
.testimonial-solid h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.testimonial-solid p {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 30px;
}
#accordion-alt3 .panel-heading h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 28px;
}
.panel .panel-heading h4 {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.panel-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: inherit;
}
.panel-group .panel {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.panel {
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
#accordion-alt3 .panel-heading h4 a i {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #2ABB9B;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 6px;
}
.follow-us {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.social-icon {
  padding-top: 6px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 2px solid #d5f1eb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #d5f1eb;
  margin: 5px;
}
a.social-icon:hover,
a.social-icon:active,
a.social-icon:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e5e52d;
  border-color: #e5e52d;
}
.contact {
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 4em;
}
.contact_top {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
}
.contact_details {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 20px;
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
}
.contact_details h5 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.contact_address,
.contact_mail {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #777;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.contact_bottom h3 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #666;
}
.contact_bottom p {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  color: #888;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.contact-to input[type="text"] {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 32.5%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #E1E2E2;
  color: #999;
  background: #FFF;
  float: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}
.text2 input[type="text"],
.text2 textarea {
  width: 99%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #E1E2E2;
  color: #999;
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  resize: none;
}
.submit {
  margin-top: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: #2ABB9B;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
}
.submit:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #22967c;
  color: #fff;
}
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .feature_grid1 {
    width: 23%;
  }
  .banner {
    min-height: 450px;
  }
  .banner-info {
    margin-top: 4em;
  }
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-right {
    right: 30em;
  }
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-left {
    left: 29em;
  }
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-left,
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-right {
    margin-top: -7.6em;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .header {
    padding: 1em 0;
  }
  .feature_grid1 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4em 0em 0em 0;
  }
  .banner-info h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  .banner {
    min-height: 400px;
  }
  .feature_grid2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-right {
    right: 23em;
  }
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-left {
    left: 22em;
  }
  .banner-info p {
    font-size: 0.85em;
  }
  .toggleMenu {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .service_box {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
  }
  .contact_details {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
  }
  .contact-to input[type="text"] {
    width: 32%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .content_white p {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-left {
    left: 18.5em;
  }
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-right {
    right: 18.5em;
  }
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-left,
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-right {
    margin-top: -5.8em;
  }
  .service_box h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .banner {
    min-height: 250px;
  }
  .banner-info h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  .banner-info p {
    font-size: 0.8125em;
  }
  .banner-info {
    margin-top: 2em;
  }
  .header {
    padding: 0.5em 0;
  }
  .content_white h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  .content_white p {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-right {
    right: 13.5em;
  }
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-left {
    left: 13.5em;
  }
  .contact-to input[type="text"] {
    width: 31%;
  }
  .nav {
    top: 70px;
  }
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-left,
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-right {
    margin-top: -5em;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .banner-info h1 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  .banner-info p {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .banner {
    min-height: 150px;
  }
  .content_white p {
    font-size: 0.95em;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
  .content_white h2 {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-right {
    right: 8.5em;
  }
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-left {
    left: 8.5em;
  }
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-left,
  .nbs-flexisel-nav-right {
    margin-top: -4.2em;
  }
  h3.m_1 {
    padding: 0.5em 0;
  }
  .contact-to input[type="text"] {
    width: 99%;
  }
  input.text {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
  BRAND
 </a>
    <div class="menu">

      <a class="toggleMenu" href="#">
        <img src="images/nav_icon.png" alt="" />
      </a>

      <ul class="nav" id="nav">
        <li id="navbar-home" class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>

        <!--<li id="navbar-services"><a href="#" data-toggle="pill">Services</a></li>-->
        <li id="navbar-services"><a href="services.html">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li id="navbar-photos"><a href="photos.html">Photos</a>
        </li>
        <li id="navbar-services">
          <a href="test.html" </a>
        </li>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jquery has a function called "toggleClass", you should first have a look at this...

Comment: ok, but then I still have to reach and toggle the previously selected element (problem #2), which isnt working so far

Comment: Just have a look at this, it should solve your problem! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845285/jquery-list-item-class-toggle

Comment: This works partially: http://jsfiddle.net/esjhwpzt/1/
However, when I change the hrefs to actual files (like "services.html"), then highlighting the clicked item does not work anymore! Why?

Comment: What are you tryin' to do? displaying the content of a file on your page without reloading it?

Comment: No,  I want to load the file referred to by href. The file contains the same navbar.

Comment: ...and the same javascript code

Comment: Then why don't you just deal with php? You have a great thing called $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], this returns the url of the page you are coming from. From that, you can : 1. Highlight the nav-bar item you are on 2. "remember" the last visited page (from the server variable)... would this solve your problem?

Comment: Btw (reading your previous message), the A link is supposed to redirect on a page, not supposed to "load content"... use another element. Or try looking at your "event handler" which would maybe just trigger once, that may be the problem.

Comment: Yes, I want to redirect to a different page - which contains the same navbar and the same js code. Thats why I use <a href>

Comment: Use the console to check what is wrong, I can only guess that there is something bad in your html or js code that makes the whole thing stop working once redirected... Do you use php on your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by generating and inserting javascript code by using a tiny python script.

Each html file now features the lines below to set its corresponding navbar element active. The ID refers to the ID which I have assigned to an `li` element
inside the list of navbar elements (check the code above).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('navbar-services').setAttribute('class', 'active');
</script>
```

However, I don' manually add these lines to each file, but instead wrote a python script to automatically insert recurring elements such as the menu bar, a footer, imports etc. by detecting instructions such as

```
<!-- #REPLACEWITH imports.html -->
<!-- #REPLACEWITH navbar.html -->
```

My script uses the processed file's name and autogenerates  the javascript code for the specific context.

The critical lines for this particular problem are:

```
comment = (line[4:len(line)-4]).strip();  # detects an assignment to insert/generate code
if comment.startswith(token):
    path = SRC_INCL+'/'+(comment[len(token):]).strip();
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        lineArr=f.read().splitlines();
        for repLine in lineArr:
            print repLine
    if path[path.rfind('/')+1:path.find(".html")] == 'navbar':
        name = file[file.rfind(os.sep)+1:file.find(".html")];
        print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"
        print "document.getElementById('navbar-"+name+"').setAttribute('class', 'active');"
        print "</script>"
```

It works like a charm for my purpose and is easily extendible